# iTunes Home Sharing from an Ethernet-connected PC to a MacBook over WiFi

Tags: itunes, network, airport, home-sharing

I have an AirPort Extreme that manages my wireless network at home. My MacBook connects to this wireless network.

I’m thinking of getting a PC and connecting it to the AirPort Extreme using an Ethernet cable (i.e. not wireless) so it gets an internet connection too.

Then I would use said PC to host all my iTunes music, and I’d like to be able to stream from the iTunes library on the PC to any Apple device in the wireless network via iTunes Home Sharing.

Would that be possible with the setup I described above? Or would the PC have to connect wirelessly (without the Ethernet cable) to be considered “part of the same network” by iTunes?

TL;DR If I connect a PC to my AirPort Extreme using an Ethernet cable, will I be able to use iTunes Home Sharing to share music from the PC to a Mac in the wireless network created by the AirPort Extreme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

I don't know how to explain, it's a network problem, and if you don't understand it, you'll need to check out some books. The easy way to say this is that they are all on the same LAN.